# Updating record from PHP Client library for Exact Online

Tags: exact-online, picqer-exact-php-client

I had used [PHP Client library for Exact Online](https://github.com/picqer/exact-php-client).

I need to store the record, based on the condition if it exists or not. Since records are saving successfully. But unfortunately records are not updating.

```
$customer = [
        'address'       => 'No.22/N, 91 Cross, XYZ Street, ABC Road',
        'address2'      => 'DEF',
        'city'          => 'GHI',
        'customerid'    => '999',
        'country'       => 'DE',
        'name'          => 'Nishanth',
        'zipcode'       => '123456'
];

// Create a new account
$account->AddressLine1 = $customer['address'];
$account->AddressLine2 = $customer['address2'];
$account->City = $customer['city'];
$account->Code = $customer['customerid'];
$account->Country = $customer['country'];
$account->IsSales = 'true';
$account->Name = $customer['name'];
$account->Postcode = $customer['zipcode'];
$account->Email = 'nishanth@gmail.com';
$account->Status = 'C';
```

From the above piece of code, based on the condition the record needs to be updated or saved from the below coding snippets. Followed two approaches:

**I Approach:**

```
if($AccInfo)
{ // Update
    $AccInfo->AddressLine1 = $customer['address'];
    $AccInfo->AddressLine2 = $customer['address2'];
    $AccInfo->City = $customer['city'];
    $updateAcc = $AccInfo->update();
}
else 
{ // Save
    $savedAcc = $Accounts->save();
}
```

**Result:**

```
Warning: Attempt to assign property 'AddressLine1' of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\exact-php-client-master\example\example.php on line 506

Warning: Attempt to assign property 'AddressLine2' of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\exact-php-client-master\example\example.php on line 507

Warning: Attempt to assign property 'City' of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\exact-php-client-master\example\example.php on line 508

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function update() on array in E:\xampp\htdocs\exact-php-client-master\example\example.php:510 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in E:\..\..\exact-php-client-master\example\example.php on line 510
```

**II Approach:**

```
if($AccInfo)
{ // Update
    $updateAcc = $Accounts->update();
}
else 
{ // Save
    $savedAcc = $Accounts->save();
}
```

**Result:**

> ```
> Picqer\Financials\Exact\ApiException : Error 400: Bad Request - Error in query syntax.
> ```

How should we need to update the records to Exact Online Dashboard?

Comment: What is the actual request sent over the wire? You might be able to get a hold of it using Wireshark or so.

Comment: How should I get to start using wireshark for packet analyzer. I have solved by writing my own custom methods, have a look. Kindly file this in Git Issue Tracker @PatrickHofman

Answer (score 1):

**Finally I solved the issue by writing custom methods**

```
$AccInfo = $Accounts->filter("Email eq 'nishanthjay@gmail.com'");

if($AccInfo)
{ // Update
    $updateAcc = $Accounts->customUpdate($AccInfo[0]->ID);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($updateAcc);
}
else 
{ // Save
    $savedAcc = $Accounts->save();
}
```

I had written my own methods from `..\src\Picqer\Financials\Exact\Persistance\Storable.php`

```
public function customUpdate($primaryKey='')
{
    $this->fill($this->update2($primaryKey));
    return $this;
}

public function update2($primaryKey='')
{
    return $this->connection()->put($this->url() . "(guid'$primaryKey')", $this->json());
}
```

For any one who knows exactly how to update to an ExactOnline. You are always welcome to answer to the posted question via built-In function call known as `update()`.